# Vanishing integral on every open ball intersecting Borel Set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Problem: Let $E$ be a Borel set, and $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a Lebesgue measurable function, and $\int_{B \cap E} f dm = 0$ for every open ball centered at points in $E$. Show that $f = 0$ $\mu$-a.e. on $E$.

Attempt:
Denote $F^+ = \{x: f(x) > 0\}$ and $F^- = \{x: f(x) < 0\}$; we focus on $F^+$ WLOG. We can define $F^+_n = \{x: f(x) > 1/n\}$. Then $F^+_n$ is Lebesgue measurable. Moreover, $\frac{1}{n}m(F^+_n) \le \int_{F^+_n \cap E} f$. Now I have trouble finding an open ball intersecting $E$ that bounds $\int_{F^+_n \cap E} f$. I tried forming $\cup_i B_i$ such that $m(F^+_n) \lt m(\cup_i B_i) + m(N)$ where $m(N) = \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, but I cannot directly say $\int_{F^+_n \cap E} f \le \int_{\cup_i B_i \cap E} f$ since on the set $N$, $\int_{N \cap E} f$ could well be a negative number. Now how should I proceed? Is there an easier way to solve this problem? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So you are assuming $f \in L^1(B\cap E)$ for each $B$ but not assuming $f\in L^1(E)?$

Comment: @zhw. well the problem tells me that $f \in L^1(E)$.

Comment: I don't see how it does. As I'm thinking about it, it doesn't really matter. But you do need to assume  $f\in L^1(B\cap E$ for each $B.$

Comment: The Lebesgue differentiation theorem will make quick work of this. Do you know this result?

Comment: No we have not encountered this theorem yet. We covered up to the simple functions and continuous functions being $L^1$-dense in $L^1$ if the measure is Lebesgue-Stieltjes.

Comment: OK. Are we assuming the balls $B$ are centered at points of $B$ or just that they intersect $E$?

Comment: I believe we are assuming the balls B are centered at points of $E$ the Borel set.

Comment: sorry to ask so many questions. Can you please write the exact wording of the problem? Also, where is the Borel set? $\mathbb R$ or any  $\mathbb R^n?$

Comment: I just edited the question, now it's the exact wording.